# error: incompatible types: NewsLoader cannot be converted to Loader<List<News>>

Tags: android, loader

NewsLoader cannot be converted to Loader> error in returning -
-> error in returning -> return new NewsLoader(this, GUARDIANAPI_REQUEST_URL + search_str + KEY);

NewsLoader is a loader class extending AsynkTaskLoader> and having a constructor with two arguments context and url.... When calling NewsLoader constructor with context and uri as arguments in OnCreateLoader having return type Loader > there is a problem in returning.. And News is a class from where all my List items are  getting returned.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. And please don't post code as images but instead copy paste as text and format it.

Comment: Can you provide more details, like is `NewsLoader` extending `AsyncTaskLoader` or what exactly is it doing; we need more details regarding `NewsLoader` class to help you solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this check the NewsLoader class and use ***android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader***

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error

> error: incompatible types: NewsFeed Loader cannot be converted to Loader

after much troubleshooting and research, I solved it by adding some of the imports to my gradle (module app), dependencies section, as shown below: Make sure to read the log results to see the likely problem.

> dependencies {
>      implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>      implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
>      implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
>      testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
>      androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
>      androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
>      implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
>      implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
>      implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
>      implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
>      implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
>   }

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
import androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
```

or

```
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
```

to

```
import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
```

in NewsLoader class.
This worked for me.